# bxslider conflict with slideToggle in only IE

Tags: jquery

I've found this jquery plugin and it works great except with IE.

http://bxslider.com/

If I insert bxslider in my code, jquery slide toggle fails.

```
   <div>
        <span><a href="#" class="tabbutton" id="tabbtnA">Visual</a></span>&nbsp; 
        <span><a href="#" class="tabbutton" id="tabbtnB">Keywords</a></span>
  </div>
    <div id="tabA" class="tabcontent">
        1<br />
        2<br />
        3
    </div>
    <div id="tabB" style="display: none;" class="tabcontent">
        test<br />
        test<br />
        test
    </div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabbtnA').click(function () {
            $('#tabA').slideToggle(400);
            $('#tabB').slideToggle(200);
        });
        $('#tabbtnB').click(function () {
            $('#tabB').slideToggle(400);
            $('#tabA').slideToggle(200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The funny thing is that if I insert bxslider.js BEFORE jquery, it works fine in some cases. (not all the page I tried.)

--fails--

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/sites/default/files/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Error- SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery-1.6.4.js, line 8602 character 5

```
/* here is line 8602 */   
 fx.elem.style[ fx.prop ] = (fx.prop === "width" || fx.prop === "height" ? Math.max(0, fx.now) : fx.now) + fx.unit;
```

--works--

```
<script src="http://bxslider.com/sites/default/files/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

**update**: if I remove this script block from bxslider.js it seems to work although I don't know what'll happen to bxslider.

```
jQuery.fx.prototype.cur = function () {
        if (this.elem[this.prop] != null && (!this.elem.style || this.elem.style[this.prop] == null)) {
            return this.elem[this.prop]
        }
        var a = parseFloat(jQuery.css(this.elem, this.prop));
        return a
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information. I'm getting the same error.
When I run any jQuery animation function (animate, slideToggle etc) I get a Script 87 error in the IEs (<9).
You're correct with that block to removed it resolves the conflict.
The effect of removing the block is that the slider will not pay attention to and css styling you have applied to it's elements and will force it's own with jQuery.
This may or may not break the slider for you.

For example in my implementation I have moved the bx-pager (the slider controls) to be below the slider inside the bx-window div. To do this I needed to resize the bx-window div to a larger height. With the conflicting block removed the slider script ignores the height css rule I added and makes it smaller. :(
The solution for me is to not use jQuery animations on the page I use bxSlider on.